# How to create wolf 3D kind of basic 3D walls in openGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d

I was trying to figure out how I can create simple 3D walls like this in openGL. I dont want to create any fancy stuff just a basic 3D wall where i can move fwd and backwards imagine it as Wolf 3D game with only map no killing etc.

[image]

Is there any framework which I can use to do this?? I want to do it in openGL so that I can create/render this thing on my iphone.

Thanks
Pranay
If any body can point me to some sample source code it will be helpful.

Comment: thanks joe  Unity 3D is very big package i considered downloading it but it failed will give it 1 more try.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-OpenGL alternative, you can construct such a maze and move through it using only Core Animation.  The textured wall segments would be CALayers containing images that had been transformed in 3-D to face the appropriate directions.  The maze could be translated relative to the camera to cause the user to move through the area.  The code for this would be significantly simpler than an equivalent OpenGL ES implementation written from scratch.

An example of this is presented by John Blackburn in his article [here](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/).

Comment: Cool idea. Reminiscent in some way of the original wolf3d which was a total hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OpenGL, then you have to create everything yourself. But there are several nice 3D engines.
Free:
[oolongengine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/),
[Ogre iPhone](http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+iPhone&structure=Development)

Payed (but very powerful):
[Shiva3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/),
[Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: thanks but how they actually create for games i have seen many games like this on iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a walk-throug in a 3D space from scratch, isn't basic stuff. It's actually a lot of math.

You will start with the 3D model of the world and in order to put yourself in the perspective of the viewer you have to transform this 3D model with a series of transformations:

- The World transformation - Moves the world map
- The View transformation - Transforms vertices into camera space
- Perspective transformation - Maps 3D space into 2D

Each of those transformations will be defined as a 4x4 matrix. Hope this helps you for a start.

Comment: Thanks, but i heard that games like counter strike is based on openGL and I personally use MAP creators which can be used to easily create map so how do they do it??